# RenderListDataAsStream Rest API not returning Field in ViewFields

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, caml-query, pnpjs

`RenderListDataAsStream` is not returning some fields specified in ViewFields.

I need to retrieve `ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl` but doesn't return anything.

If I run the following CAML Query specifying the name of the fields to retrieve then `ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl` doesn't returns.

```xml
<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
  <Query>
    <Where>
     <Eq>
       <FieldRef Name='ID' />
       <Value Type='Integer'>100</Value>
     </Eq>
   </Where>
  </Query>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name='Title' />
    <FieldRef Name='ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl' />
  </ViewFields>
  <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">1</RowLimit>
</View>
```

If I run the same CAML Query without ViewFields then `ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl` returns.

```xml
<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
  <Query>
    <Where>
     <Eq>
       <FieldRef Name='ID' />
       <Value Type='Integer'>100</Value>
     </Eq>
   </Where>
  </Query>
  <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">1</RowLimit>
</View>
```

I run these queries using `PnP.js` in a spfx web part against Sharepoint Online. Also I have a library with more than 5000 files.

Other fields like `serverurl.progid` (aka File/ServerRedirectedURL) have the same behavior.

How can I retrieve these fields using `RenderListDataAsStream`? What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you need to reference the field like this:

```
const x = item["serverurl.progid"]
```

instead of:

```
const x = item.serverurl.progid
```